# Max row sum in an array with all negative numbers

Tags: java, arrays, logic

The code below works all fine when all the `rowSum` values for each row are positive but it fails if all the `rowSum` values are negative (checks negative>0 and fails everytime) and gives answer as 0. Please suggest something to handle this negative number scenario. What should `maxSum` be initialized with ?

```
public static void findMaxRow(double[][] a){  
double maxSum = 0;
int maxRow = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++){

    double rowSum = 0;

    for (int column = 0; column < a[row].length; column++){
        rowSum += a[row][column];
    }

    if (rowSum > maxSum){
        maxSum = rowSum;
        maxRow = row;
    }
}}}
```

Comment: Well, if they're all negative, what's the sum of them? And is that sum ever greater than `maxSum`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial value

```
double maxSum = 0;
```

causes `maxSum` to remain 0 if the actual maximum is negative.

Change the initial value to `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`:

```
double maxSum = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I *hate* doing it like this: it's just crude. Personal opinion though and your approach is perfectly well-defined in Java which mandates IEEE754 for `double`; have an upvote.

Comment: this worked. thank you. I'll still wait for a few more suggestions before accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm fails since the sum of a set of numbers containing at least one negative could be below zero.

A robust way is to carve out the part of the function that computes the row sum to a function `rowSum` say.

Then, at the call site, you can initialise `maxSum` to the sum of the first row, then proceed with the other rows in a `for` loop. You can also handle the zero-rows case effectively then according to specific requirements.

Another approach would be to change the type of `maxSum` to a `Double`, and initialise it to `null`, and tweak the code that compares the new sum to the current value in `maxSum`. This way deals with the zero number of rows case quite elegantly.

Comment: for this, sum of first row needs to be calculated separately right ? Won't that be an overhead ?

Comment: Not at all: you don't evaluate the sum for a any row more than once.